# É possível que um atributo de uma classe seja a própria classe?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, lista-encadeada

Estou começando a aprender `C++` Orientado à Objetos, e tenho que fazer um algoritmo utilizando listas encadeadas. Em `C`, usei uma estrutura que tinha como um dos atributos um ponteiro para a própria estrutura. Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer algo parecido com o `C++`, mas utilizando classes ao invés de estruturas.

Segue um exemplo do que eu pretendo fazer:

```
class item {
public:
    item(int profit, item *next);
    ~item();

    insertItem(int profit, item *ptList);

    returnItem(int i, int w, int W, item *ptList);//Função que retorna o objeto de uma matriz simulada com lista encadeada

private:
    int profit;//Valor correspondente ao objeto
    item *next;//Ponteiro para o próximo item da lista

};
```

Comment: Você está tendo algum problema? Não só é possível, mas listas encadeadas são montadas assim mesmo. Claro que precisa de algum cuidado para não criar uma dependência na criação que crie um *loop* infinito, mas é raro conseguir fazer isso.

Comment: Na verdade é que eu não conheço praticamente nada de C++, por isso o meu receio ao fazer isso. Minha intuição dizia que era isso, mas eu queria ter certeza. Valeu pela ajuda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em C++ é possível que um atributo de uma classe seja a própria classe?
**NÃO**.

Em C++ é possível que um atributo de uma classe seja UM PONTEIRO para a própria classe?
**SIM**.

Detalhe: em C++ uma estrutura C também é considerada como uma classe.

Dica: nos nomes de classe, comece por maiúscula. É uma convenção que praticamente todo mundo usa.

```
class Item
{
public:
    Item(int profit, Item* next);
    ~Item();

    void insertItem(int profit, Item* ptList);

    // nao consegui entender isso, acho que e' isso que voce quer
    Item* returnItem(int i, int w, int W, Item *ptList);

private:
    int profit; // Valor correspondente ao objeto
    Item* next; // Ponteiro para o próximo item da lista
};
```

Comment: É, esse detalhe do ponteiro passou despercebido, esqueci de enfatizar isso. E sobre o nome da classe, isso foi um descuido, geralmente faço isso. Obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score 0):

Eu cheguei a fazer um trabalha para a faculdade parecido, eu tinha feito um programa com um estrutura com um ponteiro para a própria estrutura, mas depois tive que fazer um em arvore e usando classes. A única coisa que mudou é que eu tinha dois ponteiros para a própria classe.

- Criando um ponteiro para a própria classe você esta apenas criando um caminho para um determinado endereço de memória, não necessariamente este endereço estará preenchido.
- Você pode declarar uma classe com um ponteiro para a própria classe e depois ir construindo novas classe conforme o necessário, assim você criaria sua lista encadeada.

Comment: Ah, ok. Eu só tinha receio por não conhecer bem a linguagem ainda, mas se é isso mesmo, melhor. Valeu pela ajuda!